# How to open default browser

Tags: android, browser

Can we make use of default browser instead of the WebView browser
Is there ny API for the default browser.....

or we have to compulsory create our own browser through WebView

Answer (score 13):

You can use an Intent with [`ACTION_VIEW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) to open the browser with your URL. Would be something like that :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"));
```

Comment: Will this for sure open the DEFAULT browser? I can't find that in the documentation. And I found an alternative answer that also supposedly opens the default browser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23622337/2212770

Answer (score 13):

You have to import intent.

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(value));
startActivity(i);
```

value is your URL address.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but if you just need to open the default browser **without** an url you can use `about:blank`, i.e.:

```
Intent blankIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("about:blank"));
startActivity(blankIntent);
```

---

Tested with:

Stock Browser, Chrome, Firefox and Opera for Android