# How to make a the links of my website in the Android browser start up my app but not when the link has a Certain part

Tags: java, android, url, web, intentfilter

I'm going to implement this scenario:

*www. example.com* -> Start up my App

*http:// example.com* -> Start up my App

*http:// www.example.com* -> Start up my App

*https:// example.com* -> Start up my App

*https:// www.example.com* -> Start up my App

But...

***http:// example.com/dont/start/app*** -> Open the link in default browser.

by using intent-filter all the times it will open my app.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="example.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can you show the java code ?

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara Code was added.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to open the browser directly in that case.  Like this

```
onCreate() {
  if(uri is in path we don't want) {
    open browser directly via intent
    finish();
    return;
  }
  //Handle a URL we do want
}
```

To open the browser directly, you can figure out what the default browser is via [How to find default browser set on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611548/how-to-find-default-browser-set-on-android-device)   and launch it explicitly.

Comment: It doesn't work. this is the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference

Comment: Known bug.  It occurs when you're attempting to use something that requires GooglePlayServices on a device without it installed.  WHat you're doing that requires it I have no idea, since nothing discussed in this question needs it.