# Get default browser code returns incorrect package in Android <=4.4

Tags: android

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622337/6891563) to get default browser in Android. That works in all devices except <=4.4 version.

Code is

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"));  
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(browserIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
// This is the default browser's packageName
String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
```

> In other devices that returns particular package name like
>   `com.android.chrome`, but in 4.4 it is returning `android`.

I have checked my default browser is chrome. I am not able to resolve this issue after lot of search.

I have tried `0` instead of `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY`

**Steps to reproduce issue**

You can run this code in Android 4.4 version.

Comment: do you have default browser set on your 4.4 device? If there are multiple activities or no default set, then the return value is bit unpredictable and would return activity resolver

Comment: I have checked my default browser. It shows chrome, i can also check that in default settings.

Comment: Add this information to your question, so that others won't recommend it

Comment: You can check this, i have added that when you asked.

Comment: oh yes missed it +1 for your question