# Open URL in user's default browser, not in a non-browser app on Android

Tags: android

How can I make sure an `Intent` to view an URL is handled by the user's default browser, not a non-browser app?

(Specifically, I want URLs with the `play.google.com` domain to be opened in a browser, not the Play Store app.)

The only possibility I found is to apply `setPackage(browser_package)` with the package name of a browser (e.g. `browser_package = "com.android.chrome"`) to the intent.

But to find the user's default browser package [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611548/how-to-find-default-browser-set-on-android-device), I need to request package visibility for browsers in the manifest [as described here](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases).

While this seems to be no big issue, this request is should not be required because my app doesn't need to know what browser apps the user has installed. So, is there another way?