# Android Deep Link path exception

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter, android-deep-link

I have a `assetlinks.json` file that looks like so:

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.kaiconcepts.Jetfoiler",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "9F:71:88:58:AE:62:91:35:85:62:A4:A8:7B:26:00:66:5D:F2:5E:8A:CC:37:A5:A6:26:4A:AF:1C:A1:0E:53:DE",
        "E4:ED:03:DC:D9:AB:3F:87:0B:3F:AC:1D:2E:37:96:94:36:6A:86:8D:CE:25:8B:A4:CC:95:A3:A6:44:82:97:89"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Everything was working fine when someone would visit the website until we realized password reset links on Firebase were sent to the same domain but with the reserved path `/__/` in front of it. So now when people click password reset it tries to open the app but we don't have password reset capabilities in there. That is handled in the Firebase website at that url. How can we exclude URL's which contain "`/__/`?

The URL looks like so:

```
https://app.jetfoiler.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=XXX
```

This was easy on iOS:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "HW6C649LHW.com.kaiconcepts.Jetfoiler",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /__/*",
          "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Help!

Comment: I assume it will be easier to implement a check in the app for the password reset URLs and simply "forward" such URLs to the default web browser.

Comment: I’m interested in this idea! How do I do that? It would be any URL with “__” in it. One catch! I am using Capacitor Deep Links so at their mercy. I have not seen a trick to open the default browser yet!

Comment: Usually [opening a link in the web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2201917/150978) is simple, but I don't know what happens if you send the unmodified link that is usually redirected to your own app. May be you first have to [query the app for a different url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622337/150978) to know the package name you send the open URL intent to.