How to open play.google.com/store in Browser and not in PlayStore app
I have this URL that points to the data safety page of our app:
val url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/datasafety?id=com.example"

When I try from our app to open this page in the browser like so, instead of the Browser, the PlayStore app opens with the starting page of our app and not with the datasafety details.
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))

Is there a way to avoid that, and force the system to open the page with the Browser?

It feels like there should be an Intent flag for that, but I am only seeing one for the opposite scenario (forcing a non-browser).

@CommonsWare I think I found a (complicated) way but I need to test it. I found a SO answer on how to find the package name of the device's default browser. And if I set that package name in the Intent, it should (hopefully) open the URL in the browser.
Have to try this tomorrow morning though and also hoping for a simpler solution.

Here is how I solved this. To force the browser to handle the intent, we have to set the browser's package name in the intent like so:
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
intent.`package` = browserPackage
startActivity(intent)

To get the browserPackageName we can do this (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622337/61479)
val browserPackage: String? = packageManager.resolveActivity(
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.example.com")),
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
)?.activityInfo?.packageName

For this to work, we also need to add the following to the AndroidManifest
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>

A different solution (but with extra dependency)
Add this to your build.gradle
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.8.0'

Now you can get browserPackage like so:
val browserPackage = CustomTabsClient.getPackageName(context, null)

with this in the AndroidManifest
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
</queries>

